# What's the difference between the root pane and the top-level container, in Swing?

Tags: swing, panes

I understand that every top level container has some layers:

> root pane
>   layer pane
>   content pane
>   glass pane

but I don't understand whether the root pane is the top level container itself.

What is the relationship between a pane and a container? In fact, when I return a pane with
`getContentPane()`, the object is of type `Container`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the previous answers or links, you will find out, between the lines, that the actual answer to the question is:

The root pane **IS NOT** the top-level container itself, but the top-level container **HAS** a root pane.

Since all Swing top-level containers (namely, `JFrame`, `JDialog` and `JApplet`) implement the `RootPaneContainer` interface, this means that you can gain access to their root pane in a general way (no need to check if this is a `JFrame` or `JDialog`....)

About the second part of the question, the difference between pane and container, actually there is no difference, a pane is a `java.awt.Container` (or any subclass, in particular `javax.swing.JPanel`).

What is important to udnerstand is the various panes that exist in a Swing top-level container (root, content, glass, layered), for this you have to take a look at the links posted in previous answers.

Comment: -1; `JInternalFrame` is not a top-level container, [it just plays one on TV](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html).

Comment: On second thought, since this is pretty cut-and-dried, I'm going to remove that bit and un-downvote the answer; please comment if you're against this.

Comment: You're right, Lord Torgamus; I'm fine with your edit of my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You also have a `JFrame`. Read more on [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html).

[image: RootPaneContainer]
From [JRootPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html):

> The "heavyweight" components (those that delegate to a peer, or native component on the host system) are shown with a darker, heavier box. The four heavyweight JFC/Swing containers (JFrame, JDialog, JWindow, and JApplet) are shown in relation to the AWT classes they extend. These four components are the only heavyweight containers in the Swing library.